# Convergence of the sum of two infinite series only at $x=\frac12$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I would like to ask a simplified version of this question on MO: [question about infinite series](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151860/do-these-infinite-series-expressing-zetas-only-partially-converge-at-re)

Assume $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I like to conjecture that the sum of the following two infinite series:

$$\displaystyle Z(x) = \frac{1}{2\,(x-1)} \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } {\frac {x-1-2\,n}{{n}^{x}}} + \frac{1}{2\,(-x)} \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } {\frac {1-x+1+2\,n}{\left( n+1 \right) ^{1-x}}}$$

only converges for $x=\frac12$.

Is there a possible approach to prove this or am I touching on something extremely complex?

Comment: The first converges only if $x>2$, the second if $x<-2$, so there is no $x$ for which both converge

Comment: That is correct, however the sum/difference of two divergent series could also converge, right? My conjecture is that the latter only happens at $x=\frac12$ and then it is equal to $\zeta(\frac12)$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let us take $\;x=\frac12\;$:

$$Z\left(\frac12\right)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-\frac12-2n}{\sqrt n}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\frac12+1+2n}{\sqrt{n+1}}=$$

$$=\frac12\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4n+1}{\sqrt n}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4n+3}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right]=\frac12\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4n+5}{\sqrt{n+1}}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4n+3}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right]=$$

$$=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac2{\sqrt{n+1}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt n}$$

and the last series is, of course, divergent.

Comment: This proves that it is convergent for $x=1/2$. I think the OP was struggling with the "only" part.

Comment: Well, I think the above proves it is *not* convergent for $\;x=\frac12\;$ unless, as many other times, I missed something, @John ...Besides this, what "only" part??

Comment: Sorry, I judged the idea before looking at the final result. I blame the day--exhausted. :(

Comment: Welcome to the "Rats, I could have sworn over my holy cousin's girlfriend's great-greatmother's grave that I saw something else!" club, @John: I'm emerit founder, president and emperor of it for life.

Comment: To simplify his question, he is asking for which values of $x$ does the series converge, and in this case its seems the proposed value is wrong :\.

Comment: DonAntonio, there is indeed a nuance here that was also discussed in this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/140264/does-this-infinite-sum-provide-a-new-analytic-continuation-for-zetas (see the comment of Paul Garrett about the 'identity principle'. You can't simply 'telescope out' elements of both series against each other, since the individual series diverge. When you program it in Maple or Mathematica at increasingly finite series, you'll see that it does converge for $x=\frac12$ (and I believe this is the only value).

Comment: @DonAntonio hahhaahaha :)

Comment: There could indeed be a nuance there somewhere, @Agno, but I see it this way: upon substituting $\;x=\frac12\;$ in that series sum we get the difference of two *divergent* series (first term in my second line). As far as I can see, and since we can **not** sum each factor separatedly, the only way I can seem to make sense of such an expression is to gather together summands in both series and check whether we get something nice, which we didn't in this case. About what some programs do: I don't trust those things a lot. For instance, several mistakes were discovered in WA lately.

Comment: Thanks DonAntonio. Agree one should not always trust CAS tools, so please ignore my suggestion. Your approach is indeed the most obvious and natural one to take, however for sums/differences of divergent series there is a complication (as discussed in the link) to take into account when applying this approach. Still pretty sure it converges at $x=\frac12$.

Comment: Well @Agno, perhaps so...but I'd love to see an analytic proof because no doubt the algebraic handling has to be interesting.