# A function whose real part only converges (to zero) for $\Re(s)=\frac12$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

As a follow up on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619993/convergence-of-the-sum-of-two-infinite-series-only-at-x-frac12),

I like to conjecture that for $s \in \mathbb{C}, n \in\mathbb{N} /0$, the real part of:

$$\displaystyle f(s):=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left( \frac{s-1-2\,n}{2\,(s-1)\, {(n)}^{s}} + \frac{2-s+2\,n}{2\,(-s) \, \left( n+1 \right) ^{1-s}} \right)$$

only converges to zero for $\Re(s)=\frac12$. For all $\Re(s) \ne \frac12$ the function $\Re(f(s))$ diverges.

When the difference between the two ratios is taken, the conjecture holds for $\Im(f(s))$.

Highly grateful for approaches on how to prove this (deceitfully simple?) claim.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made very quick computations but, if i made no mistakes, calling $s=\sigma+it$, we get
$$
\Re(f(s))=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{n^{1-\sigma}(1-\sigma)}{|s|^2+1-2\sigma}-\frac{n^{\sigma}\sigma}{|s|^2}  \right) \;.
$$
The only hope of convergence comes from the choice $1-\sigma=\sigma$, i.e. $\sigma=1/2$. With that value for the real part of $s$, the value $
\Re(f(1/2+it))=0$ for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Many thanks, Giancane. That indeed seems to do the trick. This now shows that the summand of the infinite series in the linked question only converges for $\Re(s)=\frac12$, although I immediately have to make the caveat that the "limit of the summand"-test is inconclusive when the summand itself goes to zero... On the other hand, the latter does allow me to apply Leibniz's alternating series test, which implies that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} f(s,n)$ (i.e. ignore the limit for $n$ in $f(s)$) converges for $\Re(s)=\frac12$ only.